# Azure function (node runtime) cannot find modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions

We are deploying a timerTrigger type function to an Azure function app. This is written in typescript and using the node runtime. The function itself was working till we added a dependency, the sentry sdk (for cron monitor checks) which sound as easy as installing the module, making sure its added in the package.json file as a dependency, importing the module in the function file and done. Locally it works fine, once published it keeps complaining that it can't find certain module(s).

Now the strange thing is that it keeps complaining about 'other' modules, like 'debug' and 'https-proxy-agent'. I haven't verified it yet but maybe they are dependencies of the module that we added?

Is there a step i'm missing? Is it not installing all dependencies?

We are importing the package as follows in our code.

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node'
```

And we are publishing the function using command line tools.

```bash
func azure functionapp publish
```

I did find a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73741198/cannot-find-module-in-azure-function-written-in-typescript), but the solution isn't very clear and we are also not using vscode to deploy/publish.

Full function code:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from '@azure/functions'
import { Timer } from '@azure/functions/types/timer'
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node'

const partnerImport: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  timer: Timer
): Promise<void> {
  const IS_SENTRY_CRON_MONITORING_ENABLED = process.env.IS_SENTRY_CRON_MONITORING_ENABLED
  const API_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN = process.env.API_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN
  const API_SERVER_URL = process.env.API_SERVER_URL
  const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV

  let sentryCheckInId;
  const timeStamp = new Date().toISOString()

  if (timer.isPastDue) {
    context.log.verbose('Timer is running a bit later', timeStamp)
  }

  Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://...sentry.io...",
    environment: NODE_ENV,
  });

  context.log.verbose('Starting partner-import', timeStamp)

  if (!API_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN) {
    throw new Error(`API_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN not set ${timeStamp}`)
  }

  if (!API_SERVER_URL) {
    throw new Error(`API_SERVER_URL not set ${timeStamp}`)
  }

  if (IS_SENTRY_CRON_MONITORING_ENABLED) {
    sentryCheckInId = Sentry.captureCheckIn({
      monitorSlug: "***",
      status: "in_progress",
    });
  }

  context.log.verbose(`Sending POST request to ${API_SERVER_URL}/api/jobs/partner-import`, timeStamp)

  const response = await fetch(`${API_SERVER_URL}/api/jobs/partner-import`, {
    headers: {
      authorization: API_SERVER_AUTH_TOKEN,
    },
    method: 'POST',
  })

  if (!response.ok) {
    if (IS_SENTRY_CRON_MONITORING_ENABLED) {
      Sentry.captureCheckIn({
        checkInId: sentryCheckInId,
        monitorSlug: "***",
        status: "error",
      });
    }
    // It will retry [maxRetryCount] times.
    // See the retry settings in ./function.json
    throw new Error(
      `HTTP Error API Server returned: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}, ${timeStamp}`
    )

  } else {
    context.log.verbose(`Successfully send POST request to API server`, timeStamp)
    if (IS_SENTRY_CRON_MONITORING_ENABLED) {
      //  Notify Sentry your job has completed successfully:
      Sentry.captureCheckIn({
        checkInId: sentryCheckInId,
        monitorSlug: "***",
        status: "ok",
      });
    }
  }
}

export default partnerImport
```

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start:host": "func start",
    "start": "npm run start:host & npm run watch",
    "emulator": "azurite --silent",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/node": "^7.58.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^3.0.0",
    "@shared/eslint-config-node": "^0.0.0",
    "@shared/prettier-config": "*",
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "^4.x",
    "tsconfig": "*",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**// Edit/Update**

Also just tried to upload/deploy the function app using VScode. This changed it to a package file deployment so I am not able to se the function(s) in the azure console. Its also not listed under Functions in the VScode plugin but it does show up under workspace>functions. (From where I clicked deploy)

[image]

Hmm, im not sure how different this is yet, but probably something due to a deployment via 'package file' or something else?
Cause if i now use the `func azure functionapp publish ..` it does list it under functions.. Not sure how different this is yet.

Comment: Can you provide your function code?

Comment: Full function code provided. Updated question.

Comment: Is `Sentry` package available in the [package.json](https://i.imgur.com/jsiZWLY.png) and [node_modules](https://i.imgur.com/Db1vHwE.png)?

Comment: Yes, i've added the package.json file in the question.

Comment: Can you delete `node_modules` and check if you are still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

**Check if the below troubleshooting steps help to fix the issue:**

- Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file.
- Run `npm install` to reinstall all the dependencies. This is to ensure that all the dependencies are installed correctly and no conflicts between them.
- I feel Sentry dependency is affecting other dependencies which is resulting in *could not find module error*.
- Check if the version of the Sentry dependency installed is compatible with the other dependencies in the project.
- Run `npm ls`  in the root directory of your project to check the compatibility of the dependencies:

[image]

- If you still get the error, try upgrading or downgrading node version accordingly.

I have created a simple TimerTriggerfunction and installed Sentry package.

I could deploy without any issues as shown below:

[image]